# Easy to port compiler for a full-fledged programming language

Tags: programming

I'm looking for an open-source *programming language* and *compiler* for it, such that:

- the language is **"full featured"** — i.e. it's not a "toy language" (i.e. with support only for integers, or no access to system calls); notably, it should include support for:

  - integers, floating point numbers, character strings / byte arrays
  - composite data types, such as structs in C
- the compiler builds binaries for target platform, or at least emits assembly scripts (i.e. the compiled apps don't need an extra interpreter on target machine)

  - if this is a problem, I can accept an intermediate VM language, as long as the interpreter is automatically included in built binaries, and it's simple to write a new one (the VM language/bytecode is simple and well defined & documented)
- it should be **easy to add new backends** for new platforms; this may sound somewhat vague/imprecise, so to be more concrete:

  - should have at least 2 backends for different processor architectures (e.g. x86_64 and arm)
  - the 2 backends should be very well isolated; should have the same API/interface and be easily interchangeable in the main code of the compiler — so that I could easily see how to write a new backend
- the language should be [**"statically typed"**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_type_checking) (at least some basic typechecking; force-casting between types can be allowed)
- ideally, the compiler should be *small and simple*; the resulting programs **don't have to be very well optimized**;
- the compiler itself should be reasonably easy to work on (for example, written in Go is awesome; written in strict ANSI C is ok; written in Python is not bad; written in Java is so-so, because I need whole huge JRE; written in OCaml is so-so because the language changes too fast and it may not build anymore with recent compilers).

---

> For example, I considered
>   [MinCaml](https://github.com/esumii/min-caml), but it lacks the
>   following:
>
> - has strings etc., but has no custom data types (structs) ([section 2 in PDF](http://esumii.github.io/min-caml/paper.pdf): *"we have
>     omitted data types (including lists)"*)
> - has no memory management features (*"[many] interesting programs [...] can run with no garbage collection at all"*)
> - there are multiple backends, and they're isolated, but their documentation is so-so (the original backend for SPARC is documented
>     in [the paper](http://esumii.github.io/min-caml/paper.pdf), but the
>     others are not; also most inline comments are in Japanese)
>
> Another example, LLVM, is I think way too hard to work with (compilation of LLVM is probably not easy; also I heard LLVM is infamous for being a moving target).

Comment: I think the requirements are pretty well specified - actually this is one of the best-specified questions I've seen on this site. But I'm still curious (and you're under no obligation to respond): What's your intended use? Is this mainly for your own learning?

Comment: @JohnY Eh; what I really want, is a reasonable programming language for writing Android apps, with a super lightweight development environment (no 100s of MBs of Android Studio & stuff). I couldn't find one, so I'm asking for a language I could try to force to my needs, by trying to add a [.dex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.dex) backend, possibly via [smali/baksmali](https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali/wiki). Maybe a stupid question, but I had to ask out of frustration. By the way, as of now I'm thinking Oberon may be an acceptable answer.

Comment: Kinda late, but there's Kotlin Native. It's still a WIP, but it's built around cross-platform support